# Wireless adapter is unable to search for networks when monitor mode is enabled

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

My wireless adapter is unable to scan for access points(ESSIDs) after I enable monitor mode. I've tried using ip/iw and ifconfig/iwconfig commands to enable monitor mode, but after it's on, my wifi gets disconnected and no networks are visible. Upon checking the wireless configuration using iwconfig, I can see that the mode says monitor. I've also tried disconnecting from my wifi before enabling monitor mode, but as soon as it's on, all the access points(ESSIDs) disappear. When I use airmon-ng to enable monitor mode, only the interface changes from wlan0 to wlan0mon. It still cannot see any access points.
However, when I switch back to managed mode, everything reverts back to normal. The access points reappear and I am able to connect to my wifi again.
Can anyone tell me what's going wrong? Am I missing something? Does my wirless card not support monitor mode? But then why does the mode say monitor when i check using iwconfig after turning monitor mode on?
My wireless card is Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377. Kernel module and driver are same; ath10k_pci.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, monitor mode support seems to fall into two categories:

1. "Full" monitor mode support, where the card becomes disassociated and no longer works as an 802.11 STA (can't join a network, can't scan for networks, etc.), so that the card can simply tune to a channel specified by the user (possibly via the sniffer tool's UI) and passively listen, trying to decode any 802.11 packets seen on that channel no matter what BSSID the packets are on.
2. "Partial" monitor mode support, or "monitor mode while associated". In this mode, the card tries its best to do an *okay* job of monitor mode, while still trying to act as an 802.11 STA to keep its host connected to a network. You can't expect to set the channel successfully in this mode, because the card will need to be on whatever channel its AP is on. The card will need to change channels as it roams from AP to AP, if it's on a network with multiple APs on different channels, so that may mess up your packet capture. The card will also need to go off channel to scan for APs to roam to, so it might sometimes capture frames from other non-target, non-overlapping channels because it was tuned into those other channels while doing a roam scan (it will also miss packets from the target channel during these brief off-channel periods). It's not uncommon to see cards in this mode fail to capture packets the card itself is sending (especially low-level things handled by the hardware, such as the Acks and RTSes it's is transmitting). Sometimes they even leave their BSSID filter in place in this mode and only show you frames from the current BSSID, not all BSSIDs on the current channel.

For my needs, I prefer "Full" monitor mode support. I'd rather use a separate 802.11 NIC if I need to stay associated to some network while doing a monitor mode packet trace, rather than deal with all the struggles that come up with trying to be in monitor mode and actively-connected-STA mode at the same time.

It sounds like your card is doing the "full" monitor mode support that I like, but you were hoping it would do the "partial" monitor mode support that I find problematic.

Comment: I switched to monitor mode using 'airmon-ng start wlan0 6'. It should set my wireless adapter to channel 6 right?  However, when i enter 'aireplay-ng --test wlan0mon', it says no APs found. wlan0 changes to wlan0mon upon entering monitor mode. My wifi network appears on channel 6 normally. Even when I use 'airodump-ng wlan0mon' to capture packets, nothing happens. The table is empty.